# Is it possible to review/optimize a Hibernate query plan?

Tags: performance, hibernate

Is there some facility in Hibernate for viewing the query *plan* for a query? I can look at the source code and trace the joins and eager fetches and hope that I don't miss any, or I can look at the SQL log and try to match up a SQL statement with its source, but I was wondering if there was a faster way. e.g., I can imagine an object diagram showing the relevant classes or an E-R diagram with some kind of sequencing notation.

Comment: did u check "hibernate tools suite" software? It may speed up your process. link:- http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/Hibernate-Tools-Suite.shtml

Comment: It appears that the HTS URL is no longer valid

Comment: yes the publisher URL:-  https://hts.dev.java.net/ seems to be no longer valid. I will try to google for more links. Else I have local copy of this software on some other PC, I would try to put in some FTP website. Can you also google it?                    This is an amazing tool; I loved it during my hibernate project.

Answer (score 1):

Many times the underlying database engine will show you the plan. If you have the SQL queries being produced by Hibernate, you can prepend it with EXPLAIN

```
EXPLAIN SELECT blah blah blah
```

I'm using MySql on Linux so I can get this output without having to go through the Hibernate SQL output - I run [mytop](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/) and hit 'e' when I see the query I'm interested in. I expect most database servers offer similar diagnostics.